# PHP DOMDocument: Get inner HTML of node

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

When loading HTML into an `<textarea>`, I intend to treat different kinds of links differently. Consider the following links:

1. `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>`
2. `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>`

When the text inside a link matches its `href` attribute, I want to remove the HTML, otherwise the HTML remains unchanged.

Here's my code:

```
$body = "Some HTML with a <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">http://stackoverflow.com</a>";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($body, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    $link_text = $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($node->childNodes[0]);
    $link_href = $node->getAttribute("href");
    $link_node = $dom->createTextNode($link_href);

    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($link_node, $node);
}

$html = $dom->saveHTML();
```

The problem with the above code is that `DOMDocument` encapsulates my HTML into a paragraph tag:

```
<p>Some HTML with a http://stackoverflow.com</p>
```

How do I get it ot only return the inner HTML of that paragraph?

Comment: DOMDocument may have a rootNode to work. It creates one if there is no one. You should add a root node before to parse, and remove it manually... Hope there is a better solution.

Comment: It makes sense that there needs to be a rootNode. In that case, there might be no way around `preg_replace('/(^<p>|<\/p>$)/', '', $html)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a root node to have a valid DOM document.

I suggest you to add a root node `<div>` to avoid to destroy a possibly existing one.

Finally, load the `nodeValue` of the rootNode or `substr()`.

```
$body = "Some HTML with a <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">http://stackoverflow.com</a>";
$body = '<div>'.$body.'</div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($body, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
    $link_text = $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($node->childNodes[0]);
    $link_href = $node->getAttribute("href");
    $link_node = $dom->createTextNode($link_href);

    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($link_node, $node);
}

// or probably better :
$html = $dom->saveHTML() ;
$html = substr($html,5,-7); // remove <div>
var_dump($html); // "Some HTML with a http://stackoverflow.com"
```

This works is the input string is :

```
<p>Some HTML with a <a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\">http://stackoverflow.com</a></p>
```

outputs :

```
<p>Some HTML with a http://stackoverflow.com</p>
```

Comment: I would have preferred if there's a DOMDocument way to retrieve the child node. However, I need to preserve some HTML (including some links) and your first method strips all HTML.

Comment: @idleberg I understand. So I still suggest you to add a root tag, even if there is one, because, you could delete an existing possible one.

Comment: @idleberg I've updated the anwser. Please, see also the last part.